Understanding the Positive Divergence of a Source Point
Given a source point in a 2D vector field, why does the divergence at that point have a positive value even though the $x$ and $y$ components of the vector field seem to cancel out when considering the derivatives in the $x$ and $y$ directions? For simplicity, assume we have 4 arrows out of that point: right, left, up and bottom. The derivative of $x$ component wrt $x$ for the right arrow is positive, which if we sum with the one obtained from the left vector (a negative value equal to the right vector) will be zero.
I understand that the divergence measures the net outward flux from a point. However, when considering a source point with arrows pointing radially outward, the x and y components of the vector field appear to cancel each other out when taking derivatives, leading to a zero divergence. This seems contradictory to the idea that a source point should have a positive divergence.

This shows a very simplistic understanding of divergence. A radial vector field is $$X=\mathbf r,f(r^2),.$$ Show that it has zero divergence if and only if $f$ is identically zero, or, up to a multiplicative constant, of the form $$f(u)=\frac1{u^{d/2}},.$$ Now draw some new conclusions.
